# How do I do awesome refreshless page changes like GitHub do?

Tags: html, http, https, github

GitHub *seems* to be doing something incredible: animated page changes without breaking state. The address bar changes, but the page doesn't refresh and I get animated to the next view.

For example, hit this URL: [as3logback/](https://github.com/rfkrocktk/as3logback) then hit this URL: [as3logback/lib](https://github.com/rfkrocktk/as3logback/tree/master/lib)

How in the devil are they doing it!?! It's so cool! Are they using some sort of frame or something serverside?

Comment: @Damien, what browser/platform are you using? The animation works for me on Chrome 8.x/Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: I don't see it on Firefox 3.6.13. What browser are you using?

Comment: @David Thomas, Sorry, I retracted my comment after reading coreywards link... FF4 has the capability, not the 3.6 I'm using :P

Comment: @Anirvan: Firefox 3.6 does not support the new history API. Only Firefox 4 and Chrome 8.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They have a detailed blog entry up on how it works (HTML5 History API) here: https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider

Comment: It's so brilliant. About time they integrated this into browsers, we always had to use anchor magic to simulate page changes before, but no longer! Web citizens rejoice!

Comment: I seriously almost had a double rainbow moment when I saw this.

Answer (score 14):

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/ is a jquery plugin which supports HTML 5 History API in addition to the traditional hash tag method. This is useful for supporting the transitions in older browsers (via hash tag) while using the HTML 5 method when available.

Comment: Perfect. This would probably have been my next question.

Answer (score 10):

They most likely use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) and [HTML5 `history.pushSate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html#the-history-interface).

Note that this only works in the most recent browsers like Firefox 4 and Chrome 8 (IE 9 ?). So you would still need a fallback solution like using the fragment identifier as a lot of Ajax driven websites do now (a good example to see the difference is Facebook).

Answer (score 1):

**Pjax**: [Demo](http://pjax.heroku.com/), [Source (GitHub)](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) 
 
**It is the one that GitHub uses...** [reference](https://github.com/blog/831-issues-2-0-the-next-generation)

Comment: why negative comment??

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the question has already been answered, but I still wanted to add how everyone can easily implement this on their website.
All you have to do is insert the following script on each page.

```
<script src="https://dymc.cf/js.js"></script>
```

More information here: https://dymc.cf/documentation

Comment: This looks like a promotion. Add some pros & cons of this product and/or some sample code of how to answer the OP's question in this product

Comment: Yes, that's true, but unfortunately I don't know my way around very well. I got that from a YouTube video.

Comment: Why not post a link to that video instead. If you don't feel you know enough to answer this question, you are not obligated to answer it.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to look at the script and try to rate it. Maybe I'll find the video again. But I think my answer actually answers the question.