# new Microsoft sliding website question

Tags: jquery

Does anyone here know what was used to make the new microsoft website slide over like it does?

I want to use something like this to show 2 sides of my company like they did for business/home.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/preview/default.aspx

Thank you,

Comment: Looks like a standard slider (they exist for just about every Javascript library), but used on a much larger scale.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do awesome refreshless page changes like GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664166/how-to-do-awesome-refreshless-page-changes-like-github)

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be nothing more than a basic content slider that would exist for just about any Javascript library. One very popular library is the jQuery library (you'll find it mentioned a lot around here). jQuery (having an open plugin model) has many content slider plugins - one popular one is [jQuery Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html).

After a quick brush through the documentation for jQScrollable and loading both the plugin and the library into your page, you should be able to replicate this behavior pretty quickly.