# Change a uri with javascript and not reload the page

Tags: javascript, reload, dynamic-url

I am trying to figure out how to change the URI with javascript and not reload the page.  The action would be similar to navigating a folder structure on github where when you click a folder it takes you to a new url that is representative of the folder you clicked but the page is not reloaded.

When I change my uri with js no matter what I seem to do the page refreshes.  How can I avoid this?

Comment: This looks like a dupe from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952554/github-source-dynamic-navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at this answer? [GitHub source dynamic navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952554/github-source-dynamic-navigation/4952703#4952703)

Answer (score 0):

I swear I've seen this answered elsewhere in stackoverflow.

But, take a look at this reference on using the browser's history object:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history