# How does GitHub change the URL but not the reload?

Tags: javascript, html

Hey, I have noticed that when browsing a GitHub repository it uses AJAX to load each folder / file.

I understand all this, I was just wondering how they altered the URL. Can you get and set the URL with JavaScript? If so it could be very useful for bookmarking a section of a JavaScript based website. ( a few pages within one, moved between with JavaScript )

Thanks.

Comment: and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664166/how-to-do-awesome-refreshless-page-changes-like-github

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It uses the new push/pop state functions in the [history manipulation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Answer (score 12):

They described this html5 functionality on their blog [here](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider)

Answer (score 3):

HTML 5's [pushState](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html)