# Can I change the URL string in the address bar using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a link on my webpage, say 'about'. Clicking on it loads a particular div without refreshing the whole page using jquery `.load()`. This does not change the URL string in the browser address bar.

The same page can be accessed by going to `www.mydomain.com/?page=about`.

So what I want to do is, when the user clicks on the 'about' link, the pages will be loaded as it is (using jquery), but I want to change the URL string in the browser address bar also so that someone can actually copy or bookmark the exact page.

Is it possible to do so??

Comment: Oh. I think I got the same thing here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371705/how-to-rewrite-url-without-refresh-like-github-com

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607902/how-to-change-browser-address-bar-without-reloading-page-html-javascript

Comment: ^^ perfect answer in Felix's post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two possibilites to tackle this problem:

- In newer browsers you can make use of the [HTML5 history API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015613/good-tutorial-for-using-html5-history-api-pushstate), which lets change part of the URL, also the query string (and path afaik).
- In browsers which don't support this, you can only change the fragment identifier `#` without reloading the page (via the [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) object). That means you have to change the URL to e.g.

  ```
  www.mydomain.com/#!page=about
  ```

  [`#!` is a convention from Google to make Ajax sites crawlable](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/). As the fragment identifier is not sent to the server, you have to detect it with JavaScript and load the corresponding data from the server.
  There are [jQuery plugins](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=jquery%20history%20plugin) that help you to handler this.

I would look for a good plugin makes use of the history API if available and falls back to the hash based solution.

---

As written in my comment, you can also find more information here:

- [How to change browser address bar without reloading page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607902/how-to-change-browser-address-bar-without-reloading-page-html-javascript), [especially @ThiefMaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607902/how-to-change-browser-address-bar-without-reloading-page-html-javascript/5607921#5607921).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I've done it by doing

```
location.hash = 'foo';
```

There's other attributes of location you can change, not sure what it's called for '?', probably query-string, get, or soemthing like that.

Comment: Changing the query string via the `location` object will reload the page.

Comment: That will change whatever comes after a hash sign, e.g. you can change mydomain.com/page#foo to mydomain.com/page#bar, but that's not what the question was about.

Comment: fine look at Felix's response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607902/how-to-change-browser-address-bar-without-reloading-page-html-javascript