# Updating URL without apparent reloading

Tags: php, javascript, html

I´m building a webpage that has a sort of catalog in it, which shows the current item and its description, and thumbnails for other items below it, if I click on a thumbnail of a different item, I  have some script to change the description and the big image to the desired item. The problem is that I want this to reflect in the URL so the user could send the URL as a link to other to show the desired item. But I havent found a way to change the URL without having to reload the page, and for aesthethics, I dont want to reload the page.
Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371705/how-to-rewrite-url-without-refresh-like-github-com http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895151/can-i-change-the-url-string-in-the-address-bar-using-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973777/how-does-github-change-the-url-but-not-the-reload

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to use `location.hash`. Also, to implement it correctly, you might want to read this article from Google: [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: Uh. rather identical answers. : )

Comment: lol yeah, we were writing the answers at the same time. I posted mine 6 seconds after you.

Comment: 6 seconds *before* him. And nearly a minute ahead of me. :-) What I get for all those pesky examples.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reliable (cross browser) way to change the URL in the address bar without reloading the page - the very act of changing window.location.href (which I imagine is what your trying to do) tells the browser to reload the page (even `window.location.href = window.location.href;` will do it in some browsers).

I think you would have to put a [link to this page] element on the page and change that instead - you can easily populate it with the current URL either at the server side or using a `window.onload` function and manipulate it in the same way as you have been doing using `element.value` or `element.innerHTML` (depending on what type of element you choose to contain the link).

You can do it with hashes (see the [window.location.hash](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) property) but this can be messy programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

The usual, currently-broadly-compatible way is to use a hash, e.g.:

`http://myniftystore.com/catalog#11321R-red-shirt`

then

`http://myniftystore.com/catalog#11321B-blue-shirt`

then

`http://myniftystore.com/catalog#95748B-blue-slacks`

...as you navigate items. You can change the hash on the page by assigning to the `location.hash` property, without reloading. This requires that you use some client-side script in the first place to figure out what to show when the user first goes to the URL (by examining the `location.hash`).

Google has a [proposal](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html) out for how to make these things crawlable. Personally, I think they've really messed it up by requiring that weird hashtag (`#!xyz` rather than just `#xyz`), but if it's me or Google, I think I know who'll win. :-)

Coming down the pike there's the whole [history API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html), but support isn't very thick on the ground yet (particularly not — *cough* — from certain vendors).