# How to use .load() in JQuery to load a page and refresh on same page?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I wanted to make a site where if you click on the navigation button it loads the page and appears with .load() in JQuery (without going from index.html to about.html but only loading the content from about.html). This does work but when the page appears and you refresh, it reloads the index page, not the current page. Is there a way to refresh the current page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML 5 you can use something like:

window.history.pushState(“string”, “Title”, “newUrl”);

to put something onto the history, which will also update the current pages URL. This will update the page in the address bar, without reloading the page.

This is a similar question to:

[How to change browser address bar without reloading page - HTML/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607902/how-to-change-browser-address-bar-without-reloading-page-html-javascript)