# ajax loaded website with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if there was a tutorial somewhere on how to create a website that appears to be a single page (using jquery's .load() )..that also changes the URI kinda like the site below (I believe this site was done in mootools)

http://www.chigodesign.com/#/pl/kontakt.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does GitHub change the URL but not the reload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973777/how-does-github-change-the-url-but-not-the-reload)

Comment: Not a tutorial but here is a jquery Ajax History plugin that you might find useful http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple useful tutorials:

```
http://davidwalsh.name/basic-ajax-requests-mootools
http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-scrollspy
http://davidwalsh.name/7-mootools-plugins
```