# Generating the correct content for a page without JS when using Hash tag.

Tags: php, javascript

My page is currently loaded using a GET variable. when you arrive at the page, the GET vairable loads in a set of images, starting off with the GET variable one. You then browse these images and if you have JS enabled the Hash tag is updated to reflect the current image. If you dont have JS enabled then the page is regenerated with a new GET variable.

the problem is if someone has JS enabled and moves to an image which they then want to send the URL link to a friend who doesn't have JS enabled, the friend will receive the incorrect link, as the GET variable will be used (which hasn't changed) and the # will be ignored because PHP can't read it.

an example of this is on my site using this link

```
www.martynazoltaszek.com/artpages?nid=27#Safe Place
```

with JS enabled you arrive correctly (at Safe Place(based on #value)), without JS you arrive incorrectly (at #Dream (based on GET Variable))

[Safe Place](http://www.martynazoltaszek.com/artpages?nid=27#Safe%20Place)

[Dream](http://www.martynazoltaszek.com/artpages?nid=27)

One obvious solution is to use the GET Variable instead of the # but this generates a Page refresh, which I'm trying to avoid.

Any ideas of a solution here?

And thanks for looking.

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973777/how-does-github-change-the-url-but-not-the-reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard solution to this problem, that's why many sites place permalinks boxes next to the resources as a way to expose a hash-less link which will work on all browser.

You current url scheme is not very consistent and might be confusing because it is possible to pass contradictory information about the image in the query string and the hash.

There are ways to solve your problems but they are not standard. For instance some browsers support modifications of the URL without page reload. Another non-standard option is to allow your web server to expose the hash tag among its request variables. It is not conventional but it would allow your PHP code to read the hash.

Comment: humm. thanks for the info. not sure I'll be able to adjust the webserver to provide the hash. The reason the url scheme is not consistent, is to support non JS browsers from the start, it gets a bit mixed up if people share links between js and non js browders.
so looks like I'm a bit stuck really, my options being refresh the page to update the Get variable on each image, or expect to have some broken links.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, (sorry if this is not your case) you want a link such that when clicked to tell you if the user that clicked it has js enabled.

I think this is trivial, all you have to do is to let php know if the link was clicked from a browser with js enabled or not and then php will take the analogous action. I would do this like this:

**Share this kind of link:**

```
<a href="http://localhost/js_enabled/serverSide.php"
onclick="href='http://localhost/js_enabled/serverSide.php?js=1'">link</a>
```

**To see how it works, this is a small php:**

```
<?PHP 
if(!isset($_GET['js']))
    echo 'Oops! You js is not enabled!';
else
    echo 'Okay your js is enabled.'; 
?>
```