# Is href required on links?

Tags: html, hyperlink, seo

I'm asking this because I have some links that act like buttons that pull out content trough ajax, so I don't need any href on them.

(I'm asking this from the SEO perspective)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is href required on links?

Yes. Anchors without href attributes are not links.

> I'm asking this because I have some links that act like buttons that pull out content trough ajax

If you are doing that, then do it right. Use [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and [pushState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973777/how-does-github-change-the-url-but-not-the-reload).

"Links" that only work if you are using a pointing device and have JS turned on are not good links.

> I'm asking this from the SEO perspective

Search engines won't execute your JavaScript, so the pseudo-links (which depend on JS) are just black holes of nothingness as far as they are concerned).

Comment: Ouch - kind of harsh, and seems too black and white.

Answer (score 27):

I am assuming that by "links" you simply mean `a` elements. If that's true then:

No. At least, not in the [HTML5 draft specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-a-element):

> If the a element has no href attribute, then the element represents a
>   placeholder for where a link might otherwise have been placed, if it
>   had been relevant.

From the [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2):

> Authors may also create an A element that specifies no anchors, i.e.,
>   that doesn't specify href, name, or id. Values for these attributes
>   may be set at a later time through scripts.

Comment: This doesn’t match OP’s situation. OP doesn’t want a placeholder link, she wants a button. (Oh, and `a@href` wasn’t required in earlier HTML versions either.)

Comment: That is true. However, the answer to the question "Is href required on links" is "no". The question over the semantics of how to use such links is a different question altogether. The OPs code would pass a validation test with no `href` attributes.

Comment: Well, no. Technically, it’s not even a link if it doesn’t contain a `href` attribute.

Comment: Ok, that's true again. See my assumption at the top of my answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you have links that act like buttons, you should probably have used a `<button>` element.

Answer (score 2):

no it's not. But links may render different (underline and color) if the href is not set.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but some time ago I had a problems with "a" without href...the clicks just didn't work. But maybe it was just an old browser.

Answer (score 2):

According to the specs it is, and also you'll find browsers implement different default styling (e.g. not changing the cursor to pointer) when you leave out href. The most common approaches to adding dummy hrefs are

```
href="#" // But the event handler function must return false in order to avoid the default behaviour of jumping to the top of the page

href="javascript:void()" // has the advantage of having no annoying default behaviour
```

Comment: Common, but awful. Don't play in the manure just because a million flies do.

Answer (score 1):

They're not absolutely required, however you should probably put `href="#/"` as the href to make it semantically correct. Without an `href=""` attribute, the anchor is likely to be parsed as a bookmark in the page, especially if the `name=""` attribute is specified.

Comment: I suggest you use `#/` as using just a `#` causes the browser to jump to the top of the page

Comment: @MyHeadHurts Thanks for the recommendation. Edited my answer.

Comment: I suggest you link to something more useful then a part of the page which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not required, you should add the href to the anchor tags, because, well without an href they're not really anchor tags.

You can add a '#' to the link and add a onClick='return false;' to prevent the click event. If you're using JQuery, you can add `event.preventDefault()` to your click handler for your links.

From an SEO perspective, I'd go with using titles for the anchor tags (avoid the -ve text-indent property.)