# Link without href, any use for that?

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I was reading [sscce.org/](http://sscce.org/) and without any particular reason I checked its HTML source. I found there are many `<a>` links without `href` attribute, like this:

```
<h2><a id='eg' rel="nofollow">Example</a></h2>
```

Now from HTML [5 specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-a-element) we know that this is allowed (for example if link is *completed* later through JavaScript code), it's also allwed in [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2) (thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8970789/1207195) for references). In short it's useful if a link *may* be placed there but for any reason it has not been (server side) or it has been removed (client side). OK it's clear as it's also well summarized [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11145021/1207195).

Another (kind of) subtle difference is styling: even if link isn't rendered as link (by default underline and hand cursor) it'll inherit custom CSS styles for links such as:

```
a {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Question:** what I don't understand is the reason it's used in that page. There isn't any client-side JavaScript to add/remove `href` for that links and (more or less reasonably) I suppose such simple page is plain HTML and it's not generated server side. That said...why that links? **Is there any other use I'm missing?** Is it something related to SE?

Comment: JavaScript code may be interacting with that link

Comment: @JohnConde yes, I'm surprised they're there simply because in that page there isn't any JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check http://sscce.org/#eg and you will now.

It was an old way to create links to a specific part of the page. Back then, you couldn't reference any element on the page, just anchors. Now it works the same with `div`s having an `id`.