# Implementing search using ajax and a GET request without reloading (e.g. Amazon.com)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

New to AJAX. A little unsure about how to submit a GET request without having the entire page reload.

1. User visits `www.example.com/products/`
2. Types 'Gardening Tools`
3. Results load inline with URL changes to `www.example.com/products/results?search=Gardening+Tools` all done without page reloading.
4. Any user can use the URL `www.example.com/products/results?search=Gardening+Tools` and get the same result.

**Note:** Bullet point 4 is important. It must not be some hacky way of just adding the parameters to the URL to make it look like that. Some users might want to bookmark (besides that's why I used a `GET` request in the first place).

---

**So here is a basic representation of my code that works for  a `POST`:**

**The form**: your basic submission using `POST`, I want this to be `GET`.

```
<form id="submit" action="" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="search"/>
   <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

**jQuery**: Using `.ajax()` we send a `POST` request to `/products/results.php`

```
$('form#submit').submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'results.php',
        data: "search="+encodeURIComponent($('input[name="search"]').val()),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            //inject some html into page
        }
    });
 }
```

**results.php**: (also just to be sure am I protected against SQL injects here? magic quotes are off).

```
$query = $_POST['search'];
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
$query = htmlspecialchars($query);
//you get the point: straight forward db connect, query and return as json
```

---

So I've tried changing all the `POST`s to `GET`s but it did not work. Is there a concept I'm not understanding?

I think it could be something to do with the `$('form#submit').submit(function (e)` and preventDefault() functions. However preventDefault is required for stopping the page reloading.

Comment: To really protect your site from SQL injection, use PDO (or mysqli) and prepare your queries with placeholders. `mysql` has been deprecated.

Comment: Have you used firebug or a equivalent application to debug?

Comment: @DarylGill I'm using Chrome's native developer tools. Since I haven't gotten a response: what I did was correct?

Comment: Try using `data: { search: $('input[name=search]').val() },`. Even if this doesn't make GET work, it is a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does GitHub change the URL but not the reload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973777/how-does-github-change-the-url-but-not-the-reload)

Comment: @Quentin this looks like a HTML5 feature, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search"/>
```

AND

```
$('form#submit').submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var search = $('#search').val();
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'results.php',
        data: {search:search},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            //inject some html into page
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: There's a problem here: queries containing space will return as `Gardening%20Tools` when I output search to console.

Comment: For some reason the question was encoding the data as a URI twice, once with jQuery and one before passing the data to jQuery.

Comment: These solutions *almost work*. The URL still remains the same  @Amir

Answer (score -1):

Let me take a very simple example.

**The form:**- Action and Method are not required here for using AJAX

```
 <form id="form1">
       <input type="text" class='search' name="search"/>
       <button type="button" onclick="funcAjax()">Load Results</button>
 </form>
```

**jQuery:**- here we will define the function "funcAjax()".

**xmlhttp.responseText** is the value returned from your php page

```
function funcAjax()
{
    //value to be searched
    var searchVal= $('.search').val();
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
             document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
             //xmlhttp.responseText is the value returned from your php page
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","results.php?q="+searchVal,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**results.php:**

```
$query = $_GET['q'];
//rest follow your code
```

Comment: Thanks @Tushar. Is there a reason why you're not using jQuery's $.ajax?

Comment: No there is not specific reason, its just that I find it a little easy using the above method and moreover this is the code which I use on my tutorial website :)

Comment: you use jquery to get the value from the search field but not to make the ajax request?