# AJAX load with url but no hash

Tags: php, ajax, hash

Right now I have my site set up so that the url to each page is like http://www.tri-peoria.org/#Schedule or http://www.tri-peoria.org/#JoinUs so that I can use an AJAX loader to change pages without reloading the header. How would I get my urls to work without a hash so that they would look like http://www.tri-peoria.org/Schedule or http://www.tri-peoria.org/JoinUs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why the new web Dropbox can change the URL without page refresh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717801/why-the-new-web-dropbox-can-change-the-url-without-page-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the history API to achieve this, assuming that you handle all those urls correctly on your server (meaning, they all go to the same page).

Look at `history.pushState()` `.replaceState()` and `.popState()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

(Please note that this doesn't work in IE9 or less)

Answer (score 0):

Using `history.pushState` method. There is some support issues, so I recommend you to use a lib like https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/.