# What does #! in URIs mean?

Tags: uri

I have seen #! in several URIs, most notably Twitter. I'm curious as to what this means and where it comes from. Can anybody tell me or point me in a good direction? Google doesn't want to play.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doing links like Twitter, Hash-Bang #! URL's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952187/doing-links-like-twitter-hash-bang-urls)

Comment: I hadn't seen that. Happy for you to close the question if you need to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

Answer (score 0):

Google uses it for ajax crawling!

Source:

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

Answer (score 0):

They are known as hash-bang URIs.

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started