# Ruby on rails Ajax Edit the URL?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Here is my problem as its kind of a strange one I haven't been able to find anything on it , basically I have a page with pagination so content that has pages and I am loading the pages through ajax (so no refresh) and all of that works find however I want it to edit the URL so that if the person refreshes it stays on the page they were on (It doesn't need to change the URL just a way of keeping them on the same page)

Answer (score 0):

This is an age-old question about maintaining state in an ajax-enabled application.  There are many different approaches to solving it and most of them involve using anchor urls (example: http://yoursite.com/search_results#page2) and having your javascript dynamically build the page depending on which the anchor specified.  I recommend giving this writeup a read-through:

[Doing links like Twitter, Hash-Bang #! URL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952187/doing-links-like-twitter-hash-bang-urls)