# AngularJS "#!" on url

Tags: angularjs, web, hash, routes

someone knows what "#!" Means. on the url?

I was working until then this appears,I had a "#" always in the url and would like to keep it that way.
Currently routing is not working anymore,probably because of this url change.

It's part of a business project, i don`t want to change to html5Mode.

I tried to use:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix("");
```

Even correcting the url in this way routing is having problems

Comment: How do you do your routing ? if you're using `angular-route`, then when you loads your web, what's your URL looks like ? When this `#!` appears ? angular route doesn't work if it have no valid url like `#/report`

Comment: For reference, here's a simple routing in angular http://plnkr.co/edit/dd8Nk9PDFotCQu4yrnDg?p=preview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thats called **hash-bang**.

To fix this use :

```
    angular.module('yourApp', [])
    .config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    }]);
```

Adding html5Mode would even get rid of the '#' in the url but if you refresh the page, then you would get a 404 error. This can be fixed by configuring your server a bit. For that you might want to check the nice little tutorials :

1. https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag
2. https://www.theodo.fr/blog/2017/01/pretty-url-in-angularjs-and-loopback-drop-the/

There is another answer to the hashbang issue in stackoverlow :

[Doing links like Twitter, Hash-Bang #! URL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952187/doing-links-like-twitter-hash-bang-urls#10355561)

Answer (score 1):

You can use html5Mode in your location provider.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

more info https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Answer (score 0):

Set `html5mode` true in your app.config

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('*');
```