# Angular routes contain #! in the url instead of #

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

Recently I have noticed that when using `ngRoute` module in an AngularJS app, the route contains `#!` in the URL, which was earlier just the `#`.

For example, `www.webiste.com/#/login` becomes `www.website.com/#!/login`

I have to enable the `html5Mode` and also disable the `requireBase` which removes the base as a whole using the code,

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
       enabled: true,
       requireBase: false
});
```

and the URL changes to `www.website.com/login` which works fine but is misleading and is not what Angular SPA URLs look like.

If I do not enable the `html5Mode`, the URL is encoded and I cannot get around it. So `www.website.com/#/login` becomes `www.website.com/#!/#%2Flogin` (Notice the later `/` is encoded as `%2F`).

Is this a change implemented by the developers for some specific purpose? What difference does it make? What changes do I need to make to my app to keep it working? Am I doing something wrong?

Github issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15547

Comment: use of hash in url's goes against point of enabling html5Mode...so why are you using hashes at all? As for the hashprefix read docs regarding that

Comment: somewhere in routing(could be in app.js ), you are setting prefix like this "$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');". remove "!"

Comment: I am not setting anything like that anywhere. I enabled `html5Mode` to get rid of the encoding of the `/` (slashes) in the urls.

Comment: See [AngularJS Guide - Migration - aa0077e8](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8). This is a breaking change introduced in AngularJS 1.6

Answer (score 4):

It's called the hash bang.

For a while Twitter was using the same thing. It allows for AJAX calls and let search engines know your path without using a "real" path. It's considered obsolete though.

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

There is another stackoverflow answer about that:

[Doing links like Twitter, Hash-Bang #! URL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952187/doing-links-like-twitter-hash-bang-urls#10355561)

---

Update:

One of the reasons for not having a need for the hash bang anymore is that we can [push the history state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) without a page reload. Something so called "one page" websites, like React, do.

Comment: Why am I facing these issues all of a sudden? I have been working on small angular apps for a year now and never ran into these issues. For me the `#` worked fine. Older apps are still working fine, it is the issue with every new app that I create.

Comment: `www.website.com/login` is probably what you want to make it more search engine friendly, though. But I'm not too sure why it would just all of a sudden add the bang (!). Did you update versions recently? Maybe try a tiny sample started from scratch to make sure that it does that  by default?

Comment: Yes Sir, tried that too. Looks like an update to the module.

Comment: Then I would suggest a post to their bug list, search there first to see whether someone else is complaining. That being said, I think the bang is necessary if you want the page to be indexed by Google (not that the login page is important, but other pages are.)

Comment: Exactly, I may want to have a completely different page to be loaded at `/login` outside of Angular's SPA which does not seem doable now.