# AngularJS SPA routing getting URL as "/#!" instead of "#"

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mean-stack, hashbang

In my SPA AngularJS application, I am getting the URL as `http://localhost:4200/#!/` instead of just `# (hash bang)`. Because of this the routing does not seem to work in the usual way. 
I did go through this stackoverflow [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334798/angular-routes-contain-in-the-url-instead-of) but did not find any solution.Anybody knows the solution to get rid of this extra exclamation mark?

EDIT:
In my `index.ejs:`
I have `<a href="#about">about</a>`

In my `approutapp.js:`
I have

```js
var myapp = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
myapp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "/static/list.ejs"
    })
    .when("/about", {
        templateUrl : "/static/about-us.ejs"
    })

});

myapp.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

But the URL which I am still getting: `http://localhost:4200/#/!/`

and going to `http://localhost:4200/about` the **page hangs**

Comment: Yes, but the answer given there is not working! :(

Comment: how is it not working?  can you provide a [mcve] of the issue for review?

Comment: the url `/#/!/` is not the same as `/#!`;  this looks like it might be something on your server, not angular.

Comment: Before adding `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');` I got  `http://localhost:4200/#!/`. After adding the solution provided in the post which you marked as duplicate, I am getting `http://localhost:4200/#/!/`

Comment: Oh yes! Looks like something from my server side. Tried to run this alone without server and it looks fine

Comment: @Kshri If my answer has helped can you please accept it?

Comment: @Pritam,No actually the issue seems to be somewhere else. But thanks for an attempt to help. That's why I have voted up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('')`

The reason is:

If the browser is HTML5 browser `angularJS` will redirect it to `#!`

Otherwise it will be only `#`.

Read this documentation on [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) to find out more on this:

```
Opening a regular URL in a legacy browser -> redirects to a hashbang

URL Opening hashbang URL in a modern browser -> rewrites to a regular URL
```

> **HTML5 mode**
>
> In HTML5 mode, the `$location` service getters and setters interact with
>   the browser URL address through the HTML5 history API. This allows for
>   use of regular URL path and search segments, instead of their hashbang
>   equivalents. If the HTML5 History API is not supported by a browser,
>   the $location service will fall back to using the hashbang URLs
>   automatically. This frees you from having to worry about whether the
>   browser displaying your app supports the history API or not; the
>   $location service transparently uses the best available option.
>
> Opening a regular URL in a legacy browser -> redirects to a hashbang
>   URL Opening hashbang URL in a modern browser -> rewrites to a regular
>   URL Note that in this mode, AngularJS intercepts all links (subject to
>   the "Html link rewriting" rules below) and updates the url in a way
>   that never performs a full page reload.

Answer (score 0):

This change can be observed in angular version > 1.6.x. In previous version it was like just `#` (hash bang) only.
To get url like `#` way only, you can simply write in this way,

```
appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

This change was introduced in `version 1.6.0`, which you can see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#location-due-to.

Also, adding here what is written there:

> The hash-prefix for `$location` hash-bang URLs has changed from the empty string "" to the bang "!". If your application does not use `HTML5 mode` or is being run on browsers that do not support `HTML5 mode`, and you have not specified your own hash-prefix then client side URLs will now contain a "!" prefix. For example, rather than mydomain.com/#/a/b/c will become mydomain.com/#!/a/b/c.