# ! mark in a URL

Tags: url, urlencode, url-encoding

So this was a weird thing to find out. Recently, I was going through some angular docs and came across the - [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial). In the [example](http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-9/app/#!/phones) mentioned in 9th step, I got a bit skeptical on looking at the url.

As you can see, in the URL there's this ! mark right after #. What is this ! mark used for in URL?

I know the usage of # mark in a url, but wasn't sure about using ! mark in one. Google also wasn't much helpful in this case.

Playing with the url a bit, I came to know that -

- On removing the ! mark from the url, it was getting added again, on its own; with the URL changing to - http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-9/app/#!/phones#%2Fphones. Here `%2F` means *forward slash*, btw.

Not a huge question, maybe, but I would like to know the meaning and usage of the ! mark.

Comment: Read the [hash-bang part of this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier#Proposals) and afterwards the part about Twitter in [this article](https://www.w3.org/blog/2011/05/hash-uris/). `#` is only allowed at the end for fragments. But if you follow it up with a `!`, it becomes something else that the browser and the website need to understand.

Comment: Also read [Angular routes contain #! in the url instead of #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334798/angular-routes-contain-in-the-url-instead-of)

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the "hashbang".  It was a popular, but now discredited, way of constructing URLs.

Everything after the `#` in a URL in not sent by the browser to the web server.  After the page has loaded, JavaScript running on the page can request what appears after the `#`.  The browser then sends that data to the server, and retrieves a new part of the page.

In your example, the browser loads the page `/app/` - a script running on that page looks at `!/phones...` and uses that data to do something.

As you may suspect - it's a slow, fragile, and unwieldily way to run a website.

See

- https://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2011/02/09/Hash-Blecch
- http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs
- https://www.wired.com/2011/02/gawker-learns-the-hard-way-why-hash-bang-urls-are-evil/