# Pass url parameter without question mark and equal sign?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using javascript to retrieve a url parameter from the browser and pass it to a server running sockets.io. It's working exactly as intended, but I would like to grab the parameter without requiring the question mark or equal sign.

Instead of `/?var=` I would like it to be: `/var-` or `/var_`, etc.

Is there a good way to accomplish this without server-side URL rewriting?

**Current code:**

```
var urlParam = location.search.split("var=")[1]; // get the url parameter http://localhost/?var=[some url parameter value]

if (urlParam == null) {  
    socket.emit('newRoom'); 
} else { 
    socket.emit('urlParam', urlParam); 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share the code you are using to get the url parameter currently?

Comment: Post current code?

Comment: How about using # ?

Comment: Code is posted.

Comment: Why not use regular expressions to replace `?` with `-`

Comment: @linktoahref I want to remove the character altogether

Comment: Still a bit confused- if you want to URL to be in a different format, which is what it seems, then yes, you need to change it where it is generated on the server. With Javascript you can only parse it as it is.

Comment: @KarlReid are you suggesting that instead of passing a variable, I simply create the URL on the server? If so, would you point me in the right direction to do that in Node.js/Sockets.io?

Comment: Sure, you can do that. Do some research on how SPAs do routing using the "shebang" URLs. See [this question for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9952187/215552).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly possible to grab the url.

`window.location.href` returns the full path of the url. You can split it using `.split('/')`

So `windows.location.href.split('/')` will give you an array of strings where each element is a different part of the url. For example running it on `example.com/page/var1/var2` would give you an array `["example.com", "page", "var1", "var2"].`

Keep in mind that your server is still going to need to know how to rout requests to example.com/page/var1/var2. So if var1 and var2 are variables for example.com/page, your sever somehow needs to know to serve example.com/page.

Comment: I think this is the piece of logic I was overlooking right here.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
var urlParam = location.search.split("var=")[1];

var mapObj = {
   "?":"",
   "=":"-"
};

urlParam = urlParam.replace(/(\?|=)/g, function (matched) {
  return mapObj[matched];
});
```