# How to change url in address bar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, browser-history

I have a landing page with two tabs when i click on tabB I use js and update div

```
$.get("/users", function(data) {}); 

$('.userTable').html("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'users/index.html.erb') %> ");
```

How I can change the url in address bar also?? Every tab has function like create, edit which is also I do using ajax. How I can change url in address bar for create and update?? I check some railscast but none of them is talking about crud. Thanks a ton in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the history manipulation api:

```
//Change address to http://www.test.com/page.php:
history.pushState('', '', 'http://www.test.com/page.php');
```

See
[How do I do awesome refreshless page changes like GitHub do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664166/how-to-do-awesome-refreshless-page-changes-like-github) or 
https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider

Comment: Do all browser versions support the pushState() method, or only the lasst versions of each browsers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722815/does-internet-explorer-support-pushstate-and-replacestate

Comment: How this is going to work? from where i will get the url to pass here `history.pushState('', '', 'from where??');`

Comment: Not 'from where' but to where. Just enter the code above into your javascript code, and you will see the url in the address bar changes.