# Appending Query String to URL

Tags: javascript, servlets, web-development-server

I am taking some data from user , and then taking data from server, by a get request, sending the request parameters in query string. How should I change the URL, so that it contains the query string when it shows data for those request parameters in browser

like abc.com while showing data for param1 and param 2 should be : `abc.com?param1=val1&param2=val2`

```
$.get("/My_sevlet?asin="+val1+"&param2="+val2,function(data){addToTables(data);hideLoading();},"text");
```

when it shows results from server in browser still, the URL is abc.com.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to change the URL shown in the browser's location bar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do awesome refreshless page changes like GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664166/how-to-do-awesome-refreshless-page-changes-like-github)

Comment: What's the question? I don't understand what's the problem, querying the server? changing browser url on server answer? It's not clear, at least for me.

Comment: @TheBronx see : http://www.amazon.com/  now i search for a levis jeans,hit an enter and URL becomes: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_1_1_acs_fw_smartcategory_2?rh=n%3A1045564%2Ck%3Alevis+jeans&keywords=levis+jeans&ie=UTF8&qid=1377865147&sr=8-1-acs       Thhere is something appended to the URL , right? I am also designing a website, taking data from user, querying the server, displaying data in browser for that query. What should I do, to add such query string to URL.This is the question.

Comment: @ALBI both @Barmar and me have posted comments about `window.history.pushState()`, that's exactly what you are looking for. There are great answers and articles out there (@Barmar pointed one) so just search for `pushState` and you will find it.

Answer (score -2):

If you mean what I think you do - you cannot change displayed URL in browser's window.

Comment: That's not true. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: That is true. What you showed is manipulating the history, *not* the URL displayed in browser's window.

Comment: Read it please. Go to **Adding and modifying history entries**, there is an example and after that you can read the following: `This will cause the URL bar to display http://mozilla.org/bar.html`. So yes, you can change the URL in the browser. You can even try that code if you don't trust me or mozilla :P